# Synchronize DataSet

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, dataset

What is the best approach to synchronizing a DataSet with data in a database? Here are the parameters:

- We can't simply reload the data because it's bound to a UI control which a user may have configured (it's a tree grid that they may expand/collapse)
- We can't use a changeflag (like a UpdatedTimeStamp) in the database because changes don't always flow through the application (e.g. a DBA could update a field with a SQL statement)
- We cannot use an update trigger in the database because it's a multi-user system
- We are using ADO.NET DataSets
- Multiple fields can change of a given row

I've looked at the DataSet's Merge capability, but this doesn't seem to keep the notion of an "ID" column.  I've looked at DiffGram capability but the issue here is those seem to be generated from changes within the same DataSet rather than changes that occured on some external data source.

I've been running from this solution for a while but the approach I know would work (with a lot of ineffeciency) is to build a separate DataSet and then iterate all rows applying changes, field by field, to the DataSet on which it is bound.

Has anyone had a similar scenario? What did you do to solve the problem? Even if you haven't run into a similar problem, any recommendation for a solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSet.Merge works well for this *if* you have a primary key defined for each DataTable; the DataSet will raise changed events to any databound GUI controls

if your table is small you can just re-read all of the rows and merge periodically, otherwise limiting the set to be read with a timestamp is a good idea - just tell the DBAs to follow the rules and update the timestamp ;-)

another option - which is a bit of work - is to keep a changed-row queue (timestamp, row ID) using a trigger or stored procedure, and base the refresh queries off of the timestamp in the queue; this will be more efficient if the base table has a lot of rows in it, allowing you (via an inner join on the queue record) to pull only the changed rows since the last poll time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to store a list of the nodes that the user has expanded (assuming you can uniquely identify each one), then re-load the data and re-bind it to the tree view, and then expand all the nodes previously expanded.