# Update DataTable on every new insert in SQL Database (synchronization)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I transfer a SQL Table from a SQL Database with `SQLDataAdapter` and Fill-Method to a DataTable in C#.

The SQL DataTable recieves new datasets in a random time interval. 
Now I want that my C# DataTable (DataGridview) gets updated on every new entry of the SQL Database in realtime i.e. I want to sync these two tables.

How can I solve that problem? With a trigger in the SQL Server? With a command in C#?
*I just want to read the data.*

Comment: Related link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158617/synchronize-dataset

Comment: Thanks! But I've got not that high demands like multi-user support. Repeatedly execute the Fill-Method could work, but I don't know the time interval. It changes from seconds to hours. I just need the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me that you're in the need of MSSQL's change tracking.

I think that reading this will be a good start at least: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc714038.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Change Tracking" was the keyword! Thank you! :)  But one problem: I haven't got the "Local Database Cache" template. Also I can't connect to my SQL Server with "Add New Data Source". I'm working with Visual C# 2008 Express Edition with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1